# On [counting], [enumeration] and [enumerative-combinatorics] synonyms of [combinatorics]

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Currently, the tags [counting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting), [enumeration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumeration) and [enumerative-combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumerative-combinatorics) are [synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/combinatorics/synonyms) of [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics). This reflects what combinatorics was considered to be maybe 100 years ago, but modern combinatorics is about much more than only (or mainly) counting.

As an example, this is a selection of topics from the table of contents of two reputable books on combinatorics:

- J. H. van Lint, R.M. Wilson. "A Course in Combinatorics": Graphs, Colorings of graphs and Ramsey's theorem, Flows in networks, Latin squares, Hadamard matrices, Codes and designs, Strongly regular graphs, Projective and combinatorial geometries, Association schemes.
- Peter J. Cameron. "Combinatorics": Latin squares, Finite geometry, Ramsey's Theorem, Graphs, Designs, Error-correcting codes, Graph colorings.

My suggestion is to have [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) and [enumerative-combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumerative-combinatorics) as two independent tags, and [enumeration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumeration) and [counting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counting) should be synonyms of [enumerative-combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumerative-combinatorics).

What do you think?

Also: How is the removal of a tag synonym done technically? I did not find any detailed information on this.

**Addition**

I found this [old discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1329/61691) from 2010 which I guess led to the creation of the synonyms. The main point in the discussion appears to be that there have not been enough questions to justify a distinction of counting and non-counting combinatorial questions. This has been a long time ago and certainly is not true any more. Today, there are more than 50,000 questions with the [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) tag.

**Addition 2**

The has been a [discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26124/61691) on whether it makes sense to have [discrete-mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete-mathematics) to be a synonym of of [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics). This is a pretty similar case, and the [40+ answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26125/61691) shows a clear consensus against that synonym.

**Addition 3**

I just spotted the independent tag for [infinitary-combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinitary-combinatorics), without any synonyms. Given that, I think that [enumerative-combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enumerative-combinatorics) as arguably the most important branch of combinatorics, also deserves to have its own independent tag.

Comment: BTW you can use `[tag:tagname]` in posts - it makes the tags easier to access; the readers can simply click on the tag and go to the list of questions. I have added at least a link to the list of tag synonyms for ([tag:combinatorics]).

Comment: A related post in [Tag management 2015](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20942) by Jyrki Lahtonen.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you, I did an update to use the format `[tag:tagname]`.